# Hyperledger Fabric on Kubernetes with ingress

Tags: kubernetes, hyperledger-fabric, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using **AKS**(Azure Kubernetes Service) **to spin up** all the Hyperledger **Fabric containers**. A sample Fabric network is running successfully on AKS. But, as by default ***all the containers/pods are accessible just within the cluster.***

**How do I use ingress to expose the pods/fabric containers to be accessible with external IPs?**

I looked at some references but they use ingress-controller to define routes for navigating the request to a specific pod.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress
  namespace: ingress-basic
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: aks-helloworld
          servicePort: 80
      - path: /hello-world-two
        backend:
          serviceName: ingress-demo
          servicePort: 80
```

Whereas, we can't have any specific rules/path for peers/orderer containers.

Would be great if someone can point me towards the required configuration for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, Ingress define routes to **services** and not pods. If you have a LoadBalancer service for your Ingress-controller you should be able to expose your apps. [Here](https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/docs/installation.md) are the installation instrutions.

P.S. You don't necessarily need a reverse proxy to expose your services externally. You can do it with [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) services.

P.S.2 If you need more complex rules and requirements for routing, I strongly recommend checking out [Ambassador](https://www.getambassador.io/).

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thoughts. But in Hyperledger Fabric, services expose different ports for different protocols. Each service has atleast three ports open. The services works over TCP and grpc protocol. Not sure how would that work with Nodeport as it might get messed up to expose each ports for all the services.